# CollectionViewSource - uneven grouping

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, grouping, collectionviewsource

Im using the WPF-Toolkit DataGrid with an CollectionViewSource as Source. With PropertyGroupDescriptions I can create and display groups in the Grid. My problem is that i cannot create "uneven" groups, like:

- A

  - A.A
  - A.B
- B

  - B.A
  - B.B

    - B.B.A
    - B.B.B
- C
- D

I want some groups that are deeper than other, and some, that are only elements (C and D) and no groups. I hope it is undestandable...

Has someone an idea to solve this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use a TreeView and HierarchicalDataTemplate?

Comment: yes, i find also now other solution... but i would like to keep the datagrid =/
anyone another idea?